# ObservableArray is not updated when removing item from collection

Tags: knockout.js

I have a Multi-dimensional Array like this below

```
"ContactsList":[[{"id":73,"title":"IT Manager"},    {"id":74,"title":"Manager"}],[{"id":75,"title":"Developer"},{"id":76,"title":"Salesperson"},{"id":77,"title":"Person"}]]
```

When i remove item from array, it removes, but the main object still contains the empty array.I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5PRMe/487).

Comment: you need to conditionally remove child array (if empty) from parent array try this http://jsfiddle.net/5PRMe/488/

Comment: The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/5PRMe/487/

Comment: I have looked at the fiddle, and honestly I have no idea what it is that doesn't work. This is the output: Removed {"id":73,"title":"IT Manager"}
It was not updated [[{"id":74,"title":"Manager"}],[{"id":75,"title":"Developer"},{"id":76,"title":"Salesperson"},{"id":77,"title":"Person"}]] .. Seems like the one with id 73 was removed?

Comment: @steen Tottrup, when i removed item from nested observable array, when all items removed from the array, empty array will remains there. super cool has solved the problem to conditionally remove child array (if it is empty) from parent array.he has update the fiddle, jsfiddle.net/5PRMe/488/

Comment: Thanks, @super cool, it solved my problem